# Running windows docker in virtual machine crashing

Tags: docker

I am running windows docker on a virtual machine and when i try to run docker run, it crashes the vm as well saying unhandled exception. And get logged out of the vm

The vm is windows server 2016 running on a host that is 2012.

The docker version info

```
Client:
 Version:      17.06.2-ee-6
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   e75fdb8
 Built:        Mon Nov 27 22:46:09 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.2-ee-6
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.24)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   e75fdb8
 Built:        Mon Nov 27 22:55:16 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

The docker logs get corrupted for this specific container I am trying to run each time that I try to run the docker. So i cant diagnose what happened. Please suggest what i can do.

Comment: Please share more details on what is your VM OS and which docker version you are exactly running..

Answer (score 0):

In a windows OS I ended up running docker inside a vagrant debian/centos box. 
It's ligthweight and never had a problem.

Comment: Running a linux docker is not an option at the moment cuz of strong team preferences